# Grepping Numbers With Decimal Places

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to figure out how to grep a time stamp read from a file that consists of a number with a decimal, but I can't seem to get the output I'm looking for, any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
[Time since reference or first frame: 691.933275000 seconds]
[Time since reference or first frame: 691.953127000 seconds]
[Time since reference or first frame: 691.992275000 seconds]
[Time since reference or first frame: 691.997590000 seconds]
```

The result should be:

```
691.933275000
691.953127000
691.992275000
691.997590000
```

What I've Tried:

```
grep '[0-9]\.[0-9]' tmp.txt
grep -Eo '[0-9]\.[0-9]' tmp.txt
grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,10}[\.]){1,10}[0-9]' tmp.txt
```

Comment: Is it there only these content in file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `awk` to split the file to retrieve those fields which has decimal number

```
cat file_name | awk '{print $7}'
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! I should have thought about awk.

Comment: Get rid of the UUOC though - `awk '{print $7}' file_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it could be solved using Perl:

```
perl -lane 'for (@F) {print if /^\d+\.?\d+$/}' file
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print the line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the @F array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace
- `-e` execute the perl code

The perl code splits each input line into the @F array, then loops over every field and decides whether or not to print it.

The regular expression `/^\d+\.?\d+$/` is used on each whitespace-delimited word

- `^` starts with
- `\d+` one or more numerals
- `\.?` zero or one .
- `\d+` one or more numerals
- `$` end

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cut -d' ' -f7 file
691.933275000
691.953127000
691.992275000
691.997590000
```